# How do i make my website comoatible across all browsers

Tags: cross-browser

I just finished working on this landing page and it looks very well on my chrome browser and all other browsers on my machine. Now the problem is the person I created it for says it doesn't look good on Firefox and other browsers but sits well on chrome. Here is the temporary site link https://bejewelled-naiad-bd5583.netlify.app/ please open on your pc as it isn't yet suitable for mobile. Let me know if it sits well on all browsers thanks.